# Performance of database partitioned across multiple Azure Data Disks

Tags: azure, azure-storage, partitioning, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

Would partitioning a SQL Server database across separate page blobs (Azure Data Disks) have a performance impact when querying `partition 1` if `partition 2` is under heavy load?

I understand the page blobs aren't necessary separate physical disks, so I'm wondering about the performance.

**Context edit:**  Basically I want to partition old (archive) data away from the live data (so everything over 3 months old) to reduce the database and index size.  But this archive data must still be queryable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely an "it depends" answer and will take some testing on your part.

The [2012 Scalability Targets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/02/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx) show a blob at about 60 MB/sec while the [VM sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee814754.aspx) show an Extra Large instance gets 800 Mb/sec - the target throughput is obviously dependent on your usage, so you may or may not be able to get close to that figure and if you can, you're probably saturating your allotted bandwidth so absolutely no point going any further.

I'd be inclined to go with a basic configuration of each database instance getting 1 drive for data, 1 drive for logs. If you still have any headroom on your network then you can look at partitioning further as appropriate.

Alternatively, you could perhaps look at using [Data Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894051%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) if your issue is with how fast you're able to retrieve data from the blob underlying your azure drive...

Answer (score 1):

If your query doesn't need to fetch data from Partition 2 I suspect the impact would be minimal. However if your objective is to improve performance did you consider creating a RAID 0 (stripe) with blobs?

Comment: Basically I want to partition old (archive) data away from the live data (so everything over 3 months old) to reduce the database and index size.  But this archive data must still be queryable.  How do I create a RAID 0 stripe with blobs?  I can't find any resources. Thanks!

Comment: You need to attach 2 or more new disks to your VM using the Attach button on the Azure Portal. Make sure the disks are of the same size. Then, once they have been created, go to your VM and use Disk Manager to initialize your 2 disks; once initialized you can then create a RAID 0 volume, which starts a wizard allowing to pick your 2 disks.